# On the equivalence condition of p.p. rings

Tags: ring-theory, projective-module, idempotents

A ring is known to be left p.p. if every principal left ideal is projective. It is well known that this condition is equivalent to the fact that every annihilator of each element is generated by an idempotent. However, I cannot easily see how this works. Can anyone give me at least a hint? It will be a great help for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The sequence
$$
0\rightarrow Ann(r)\rightarrow R \rightarrow Rr\rightarrow 0
$$
splits, hence every such anihilator $Ann(r)$ is a summand of $R$, and hence has the form $Re$ for an idempotent $e$ in $R$.
A possible reference is [this book](https://books.google.at/books?id=ud8MV2C76RYC&pg=PA343&lpg=PA343&dq=properties+of+p.p.-rings+idempotent&source=bl&ots=1EDLzps4n5&sig=pwtfs8ITc8zmKWN4vlzG_D_YjUA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB2Nalk_rKAhVHfhoKHdKEBAkQ6AEIXDAH#v=onepage&q=properties%20of%20p.p.-rings%20idempotent&f=false) on ring theory.
More references on PP-rings and Baer rings, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baer_ring).

Comment: I wonder how much is possible without the assumption of multiplicative identity. I do not work with these things much, but ostensibly this condition is amenable to study for rngs.